share power bi dashboards, without work/school e-mail ID
I want to publish my power bi dashboards online to share with recruiters , but when i try to log in it tells me to 'use work/school email id' which i don't have.i have tried my personal e-mail id, but it will not accept it.  Is there any way to share my dashboards without having to create a work/school email?

The Power BI Service doesn't allow you to create accounts using email services

Power BI requires that you use a work or school email address. You
can't sign up or purchase using email addresses provided by consumer
email services or telecommunication providers. These services include
outlook.com , hotmail.com , gmail.com , and others

As outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/service-self-service-signup-for-power-bi
You have the option of registering your own domain, then typically paying for the email service for yourdomain.com, which will allow you to register a PBI Account.
The other option is to create PDF's/Screenshots from your items, and have to use those static items to send to recruiters.
